# Is using SHA-1 considered an app with encryption?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I'd like to use `SHA-1` as index keys for my data. In the during the app approval process, does iTunesConnect consider using SHA-1 as an app with encryption embedded? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From a purely technical standpoint, they shouldn't - SHA-1 is not encryption, as the data transformed with it aren't recoverable.

However, Apple and its minions have been known to have occasional fits of rejecting apps "because they can."

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get the implementation from? I think we have used some hashing function in the past, did not check the encryption checkbox somewhere on the submit page and got through the review just fine.

Comment: I am going to use UnRAR, in which I found some SHA-1 implementations.